# javascript / selenium: get the window from the document object

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, selenium, document

I am writing user extensions to selenium. I have the `document` object. How can I get the `window` object of the window that contains my document?

```
PageBot.prototype.locateElementByMyLocator= function(text, inDocument) {
     // I want the window here
}
```

Comment: How did you get the document object in the first place? I seem unable to fetch it during the test run...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IE it's document.parentWindow; in Mozilla it's document.defaultView.

Thus you could do something like

```
function getDocWindow(doc) {
  return doc.parentWindow || doc.defaultView;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing your own extension you can get a window object in Selenium by going

```
Selenium.prototype.doExtensionStuff(){
   var doc = this.browserbot.getUserWindow().document; //This returns the document that Selenium is using

}
```

This is seen as a better way of doing and will work on any browser since Selenium is taking care of the different browser nastiness